# in_array from array in txt file not working for int greater than ten

Tags: php, arrays, random

I've tried this

```
$randtxt = fopen('random.txt','r');
$zawa = fread($randtxt, 8192);
$tt = str_split($zawa);


do {

    $numer = rand(8, 11);

} while (in_array($numer, $tt));


echo<<<END
$numer
END;
```

Random.txt contains in this example:

```
"8", "9", "10",
```

The only one solution for this script is 11 at the end, but it's 10 sometime too (I don't know why), it's sometime 10, but never 1, 2, 3 ... 9. It's not working for int greater than 10.

I've tried with this, but it's not even working too

```
$randtxt = file_get_contents('random.txt');
$inarr = unserialize($randtxt);

$number = 11;       

if (in_array($number, $inarr, true))
{
    echo "yup";
}
else
{
    echo "nope";
}

    $numberout = serialize($number);
    $out = file_put_contents('random.txt', $numberout, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: try [mt_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)

Comment: You split your string into an array of characters. You don't have any array element longer than 1 character. So every 2 or more digit number will not be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to output the `$tt`-array? It contains this:
`Array ( [0] => " [1] => 8 [2] => " [3] => , [4] => [5] => " [6] => 9 [7] => " [8] => , [9] => [10] => " [11] => 1 [12] => 0 [13] => " [14] => , [15] => )`

No wonder `10` shows up sometimes... You need to fix how you make that array, first off you need to split the content properly, and remove spaces (use trim()), double quotes and commas.

The following code works:

```
<?php
$randtxt = file('random.txt');
$tt = str_replace(',','',str_replace('"','',explode(' ',$randtxt[0])));

do {
    $numer = rand(8, 11);
} while (in_array($numer, $tt));


echo<<<END
$numer
END;

?>
```